# Telerik MVC grid issue in insert mode without edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

HI
I have telerik mvc grid in ajax mode and editing is enabled. In my scenario i have to use only the insert mode so I disabled the edit mode. but when I run i get the javascript error on click of "Add New Record". Sample project can be downloaded from [Here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/issue-in-insert-mode-without-edit-mode.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by the following:

```
function GridNotes_onEdit(e) {
    $('#Content').after("<a class='t-button t-grid-cancel t-button-icon' href='#'><span class='t-icon t-cancel'/></a>")
        .after("<a class='t-button t-grid-insert t-button-icon' href='#'><span class='t-icon t-insert'/></a>");
}
```

Now, this worked when I only had one field being inserted.  If you have multiple columns, you may need to customize it to your specifications.  But it is do-able.  As well, it worked in a detail view grid.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I had to modify the code a bit to get it working in my situation. I used `$('.t-grid-new-row td:nth-child(6)').html('< class...` in the OnEdit function, where the 6 (1 based) was the column I wanted to put my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an official support channel as you provided a sample project, post your request to the telerik MVC forums on their site.

Comment: the link is from there post but got no response yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. The answer is in-line needs the edit buttons to be there, so with in-line mode the insert breaks

This link covers this and has a fix.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/insert-only-with-server-editing.aspx